# Upgrading project target to iOS 9.0

Tags: ios, swift2, ios9

I have been working on a project which started off on XCode 7 beta using Swift 2.0 and targeting iOS 8.0 (now using Xcode 7 general release). In order to take advantage of storyboard referencing I decided to upgrade target to iOS 9.0.

I am getting this error -> `module file's minimum deployment target is ios9.0 v9.0: ... cwygdmgyjbvuhydjcsqsqzzqjpvz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/bpos.swiftmodule/arm.swiftmodule`

Edit: I have noted that this error only appears on those classes that are targeting the test project build

This is the closest that I got to my question with answer -> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307117/error-module-files-minimum-deployment-target-is-ios8-3-v8-3)

Unfortunately nothing of that answer has worked. I have tried cleaning and building plenty of times, changing devices, clearing devices cache. Nothing has worked. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in many places but it look different from the answers images.

Answer: [Can no longer import app module into unit tests after changing deployment target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461012/can-no-longer-import-app-module-into-unit-tests-after-changing-deployment-target)

The deployment target settings of the test target that was needed to change, the title was labeled **(null) - Deployment** which threw me into a confusion. I have no idea why it is labeled such way, maybe something to do with some other settings which might had been modified by the previous developers working on the project.

Hope it helps someone.